# Filtered query error

Tags: elasticsearch

```
GET dspdocs/_search
{
 "query": {
  "filtered": {
    "filter": {
      "bool": {
        "must": ["must_term1", "must_term2"],
        "must_not": ["must_not_term", "must_not_term2"]
        }
      },
    "query": {
      "match": {
        "text": {
          "query": "query_term",
          "operator": "or"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
}
```

I am trying to execute the above query and I get the following error:

```
"type": "query_parsing_exception",
"reason": "[_na] query malformed, must start with start_object",
```

I know this means that my query hasn't been written properly or I've screwed up some order somewhere but for the life of me, I can't seem to figure out where I went wrong.

I'm basically trying to filter out all documents which don't contain the must terms and contain the must_not terms. Then I search within the filtered set for all documents which have the query_term in them.

(I do the filtering first to increase the speed of the search slightly)

Comment: Could you given an example of `must_term1` and `must_not_term` ? Are they term queries or just a `query_term` ?

Comment: They are just strings, just needed to convert them into term queries like pickypg showed below and it works!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is in the example:

```
...
  "bool": {
    "must": ["must_term1", "must_term2"],
    "must_not": ["must_not_term", "must_not_term2"]
    }
  },
...
```

The array of `must` and `must_not` (and `should` and `filter` for that matter) expects either a single *object* or an array of *objects*. For example:

```
"bool": {
  "must": [
    {
      "term" : {
        "my_field" : "must_term1"
      }
    },
    {
      "term" : {
        "my_field" : "must_term2"
      }
    }
  ],
  "must_not": [
    {
      "term" : {
        "my_field" : "must_not_term"
      }
    },
    {
      "term" : {
        "my_field" : "must_not_term2"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Note that I am using the `term` query, but you're free to use any type of query. With Elasticsearch 2.x+, you should write this as a pure `bool` query, rather than a `filtered` one:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "query_string" : {
            "query" : "query_term"
          }
        }
      ],
      "must_not": [
        {
          "term" : {
            "my_field" : "must_not_term"
          }
        },
        {
          "term" : {
            "my_field" : "must_not_term2"
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": [
        {
          "term" : {
            "my_field" : "must_term1"
          }
        },
        {
          "term" : {
            "my_field" : "must_term2"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```